# Require solution to click on button appearing on OWA screen

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver, automation, outlook-web-app

My test script are developed using Java with Selenium webdriver api. There is 1 particular scenario where I need to click on a button but I am not able to do that. Following are the test steps and the screenshot for the particular problem.

-Launch OWA(Outlook webapp)
-Create a recurring event in Calendar
-Goto Calendar and click the event
-A popup is displayed with 2 buttons ([Screenshot](http://i68.tinypic.com/345yasy.png))

-I need to click these buttons

[Button Screenshot](http://i68.tinypic.com/345yasy.png)

I have tried few solutions such as switching frames, handling alert box etc but nothing has helped yet.

How to handle such dialog box.

Comment: please post HTML code

Comment: [tag:Mona]

<div class="btnDlg">
<div class="dlgSpacer"/>
<div id="divBtnDlgBdy" class="dlgBdy">
<div class="dlgPrMsg">Do you want to open only this occurrence or the series?</div>
<div class="dlgBtns">
<button id="btn0" iicntp="0" style="width: 112px;">This Occurrence</button>
<button id="btn1" iicntp="1" style="width: 112px;">The Series</button>
</div>
</div>

([Screenshot](http://i68.tinypic.com/8vx53n.png))

Comment: how you clicking the event? its happening to me at all

Comment: You just need to double click the reoccurring event. Goto to Calendar and double click the event.

Comment: got it. the list of calendar event contents is under iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tested in my outlook app. it executed well.

please find the coding,

```
  public class testngchecktwo  {

    static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  @Test
  public void testa() throws InterruptedException {
      driver.get("https://company.com/owa");
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
      driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("me@company.com");
      driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("pass");
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Sign in']")).click();

      Thread.sleep(5000);
      //click clanedar icon
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='lnkQlCal']/img")).click();
      Thread.sleep(5000);


      //switch to frame where events listed
      driver.switchTo().frame("bLgAAAAA/GWQ3xtO0SIOqswLk6uH4AQDVKQ5oRivJSZbc9pQXHu/BAAAAbHJJAAAC");

      //Click Enter to bring up that small popup instead double click in mouse
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='divVisualTextContainer']")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

     //get hack to orginal window
      driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

      //click this occurance button
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='btn0']")).click();

  }
}
```

Comment: May be iframe Id would change.

Comment: [tag:Mona] Your suggestion worked. I was not using the hack which you provided in 2nd last steps. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Please don't use `Thread.sleep()`, it's bad practice. Use `WebDriverWait` instead. BTW, that isn't a hack, that's how you switch the context back from an `IFRAME`.

Comment: It's typo. I meant back :) thanks for advice. For quick testing I used thread.sleep()

Comment: Appreciate your inputs.